# Django - How to extract the file names from a file input element?

Tags: python-3.x, django-templates, htmx

I'm trying to implement a form in Django, where one of the inputs is a list of file names.  I don't need to access the files themselves or upload them, I only need an easy-on-the-user way to get a list of file ***names,*** then supply that list along with the other form data.

The approach I'm trying to use is to have a multiple-file input element in my template, then use htmx to extract the file names from that element.  But no matter what I try, I can't seem to get at the file names -- all that comes through is the string, `'%5Bobject%20File%5D'`.

**I expect this is a newbie error, or possibly my approach is just wrong from the outset... but either way, can someone point me in the right direction to get the actual names of the entered files?**

*(Note, the following is highly simplified redux of my actual code, to focus in on the problem.)*

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path("home_1b/", home_1b, name="home_1b"),
    path("", home, name="home"),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def home_1b(request):
    print('*********************')
    print(request)
    print(request.GET)
    print(request.GET['fi_file_names'])
    print(request.FILES)
    print('*********************')
    return render(request,'home_1b.html')
```

home.html:

```
<!-- templates/home.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block head %}
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static '/htmx/htmx.min.js' %}"></script>
<style>
    .column {float:left; width:50%;}
    .row:after{content:""; display:table; clear:both;}
    label {font-family:Verdana; font-size:small;}
    input[type="file"] {width:350px; padding:1px 3px 1px 3px; font-family:Verdana; font-size:small;  border-style:solid; border-width:1px; background-color:lightgray;}
    input[type="file"]::file-selector-button {display:none;}
</style>
{% endblock head %}
{% block content %}
<h2>File name entry</h2>
<div id="home_r1c1" class="row">
    <h3>Enter the file name(s) to be cited in the report</h3>
    <div id="home_1a_slot" 
    hx-get="{% url 'home_1b' %}"
    hx-trigger="change"
    hx-encoding="multipart/form-data"
    hx-target="#home_1b_slot"
    hx-include="#fi_file_names">
        <label for="fi_file_names" style="border:1px solid; border-radius:3px; padding:1px 5px 1px 5px; background-color:lightgray;">...</label>
        <input type='file' multiple id="fi_file_names" name="fi_file_names"></input>
    </div>
    <h3>Review the files specified</h3>
    <div id="home_1b_slot">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

At this point, `home_1b.html` is only a stub.  (I haven't bothered coding it yet due to the basic problem mentioned.)

Output when I run the server and try to input one file:

```
*********************
<WSGIRequest: GET '/home_1b/?fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D'>
<QueryDict: {'fi_file_names': ['[object File]']}>
[object File]
<MultiValueDict: {}>
*********************
[04/Oct/2023 15:03:50] "GET /home_1b/?fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D HTTP/1.1" 200 56
```

Attempting multiple files, I get:

```
*********************
<WSGIRequest: GET '/home_1b/?fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D&fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D&fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D'>
<QueryDict: {'fi_file_names': ['[object File]', '[object File]', '[object File]']}>
[object File]
<MultiValueDict: {}>
*********************
[04/Oct/2023 15:05:26] "GET /home_1b/?fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D&fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D&fi_file_names=%5Bobject%20File%5D HTTP/1.1" 200 56
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the  that posted to the request had enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, FILES will be a blank dictionary-like object.

So, change your html.

```html
<form hx-post="{% url 'home_1b' %}" hx-target="#home_1b_slot" hx-trigger="change from:#fi_file_names" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Enter the file name(s) to be cited in the report</h3>
    <label for="files">Select files:</label>
    <input type="file" name="fi_file_names" id="fi_file_names" multiple>
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
</form>
    
<h3>Review the files specified</h3>
<ol id="home_1b_slot"></ol>
```

Then in your views, use `request.FILES.getlist()` to retrieve all the selected files (each file will be an instance of [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) and, therefore, will have a `name` attribute you can use to get the file name.

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

def home_1b(request):
    user_files = request.FILES.getlist("fi_file_names")
    data = ""
    for file in user_files:
        data += f"<li>{file.name}</li>" # file is an UploadedFile instance, has 'name' attribute.
    data = mark_safe(data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: Thanks but as I said in the question, I don't need to access the files themselves or upload them.  I only need an easy-on-the-user way to get a list of file names, then supply that list along with the other form data.  Uploading the files for this use case is unnecessary overhead that will slow down things on the user's end, and require me to delete the uploaded files so they don't fill up the server.

Comment: This won't upload or save them anywhere. The `UploadedFile` is just a class for files submitted through a form.

Comment: "During file uploads, the actual file data is stored in request.FILES. Each entry in this dictionary is an UploadedFile object (or a subclass) – a wrapper around an uploaded file."  At the very least this is reading the file data and sending it to the server in the POST request.  That's the overhead I'm looking to avoid.  (The files involved here may be several GB in size.)